# Is there a way to check who did the action (e.g deleted channel)

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

I'm working on a bot and i was wondering is there a way to check who did the event? Like someone deletes a channel/role, how could i see who was the user behind that?

I've tried `async def on_guild_channel_delete(ctx, member):`, but it returns `TypeError: on_guild_channel_delete() missing 1 required positional argument: 'member'`.

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**Edit**
To parse the [audit logs](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#discord.Guild.audit_logs) on channel delete events, try this (your bot will need permissions to View Audit Log):

```
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
    entry = await channel.guild.audit_logs(action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete, limit=1).get()
    print("User {} deleted channel {} at time {}".format(entry.user.name, channel.name, entry.created_at))
```

Output on channel delete event:
`User MyDeleter deleted channel my-test-channel at time 2020-09-22 03:08:11.638000`
What's happening: `guild.audit_logs()` returns the entries into an audit log for a guild (we get the guild from `channel.guild`).
`.get()` returns the first item in that iterator, which will be the newest entry.
`action=discord.AuditLogAction.channel_delete` will only look for entries that deleted channels.
`limit=1` will at max return 1 event. Useful for writing iterators, but this is unnecessary if using `.get()`, but I'd leave it anyways in case there is an efficiency benefit (in truth, I forgot it was there until I was writing this).

Regarding getting the deleter from a channel delete event (original answer):
From the [docs](https://www.curseforge.com/minecraft/mc-mods/jellyfishing)

```
>  discord.on_guild_channel_delete(channel)  
>    Called whenever a guild channel is deleted or created  
>  Parameters  
>     channel (abc.GuildChannel) – The guild channel that got created or deleted.
```

The only parameter available is `channel`.
The same limitation applies for role, the only parameter being `role`.
If you wanted this information for moderation purposes, Discord stores this information in Server Settings > Audit Log

Further:
I notice you are calling it with a parameter ctx (context), it is good practice for events to refer to the parameter by what it specifically is, because it does not carry a lot of information (context) like a command's first parameter might.
Call it like this:

```py
@client.event
async def on_guild_channel_delete(channel):
   print("A channel was deleted")
```

Comment: thank you so much man, this worked AND you explained how!